# ActiveMailer Email Not Sending from Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of emails that are supposed to send out from within a rake task.

Here's the entire `send_notifications.rake` file:

```
desc "Send today's notifications."
task send_notifications: :environment do
  require 'time'
  puts 7.days.from_now
  
  phases = TeamProjectPhase.all
  phases.each do |phase|
    if phase.ends == 7.days.from_now && !phase.admin_confirmed
      TeamMailer.due_date_approaching(phase).deliver
    end
  end

  phases = TeamProjectPhase.all
  phases.each do |phase|
    if phase.ends.today? && !phase.admin_confirmed
      TeamMailer.due_date_here(phase).deliver
    end
  end

  phases = TeamProjectPhase.all
  phases.each do |phase|
    if phase.ends.today? && !phase.admin_confirmed
      TeamMailer.due_date_missed_admin(phase).deliver
    end
  end

  tasks = TeamTask.all
  tasks.each do |task|
    if task.due == 7.days.from_now && !task.admin_confirmed
      TeamMailer.task_due_date_approaching(task).deliver
    end
  end

  tasks = TeamTask.all
  tasks.each do |task|
    if task.due.today? && !task.admin_confirmed
      TeamMailer.task_due_date_here(task).deliver
    end
  end

  tasks = TeamTask.all
  tasks.each do |task|
    if task.due.today? && !task.admin_confirmed
      TeamMailer.task_due_date_missed_admin(task).deliver
    end
  end

end
```

I have used `puts` to determine that when I do `run rake send_notifications` it is reaching inside the correct if statements for the correct task and/or phase.

Unfortunately, none of the emails are sending!  I've tried ending them with `deliver` and `deliver_now`.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What email service are you using, (if any)? And how are you configuring it, that is almost always the issue.

Comment: @Eyeslandic I'm using Sendgrid via Heroku, and fortunately/unfortunately all the other emails from the same mailer are sending just fine.

Comment: There must be some logs you can look at to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of code cleanup so you aren't looping more than you need to:

```rb
desc "Send today's notifications."
task send_notifications: :environment do
  require 'time'
  puts 7.days.from_now

  TeamProjectPhase.all.each do |phase|
    return unless phase.admin_confirmed
    
    TeamMailer.due_date_approaching(phase).deliver if phase.ends == 7.days.from_now
    
    if phase.ends.today?
      TeamMailer.due_date_here(phase).deliver
      TeamMailer.due_date_missed_admin(phase).deliver
    end
  end

  TeamTask.all.each do |task|
    return unless task.admin_confirmed

    TeamMailer.task_due_date_approaching(task).deliver if task.due == 7.days.from_now

    if task.due.today?
      TeamMailer.task_due_date_here(task).deliver
      TeamMailer.task_due_date_missed_admin(task).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

If `TeamMailer` is not sending, but other mailers send, I'd compare `TeamMailer` to a working mailer to see what I might have forgotten to set (e.g. `default from: "from@example.com"` or `layout 'mailer'`)

If `TeamMailer` sends in other cases, but not from the `rake` task, I'd use a debugger to check:

1. `ActionMailer` queue to see if the email gets queued to send
2. `ActionMailer` [configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-mailer)  to make sure things like `perform_deliveries` is still `true`
3. The `:environment` settings and my environment file to make sure I'm not overriding something.